# Remove text after last /

Tags: text

I have list of links like:

```
http://site1.com/lalala.html
http://site2.com/lalala/
```

And I need to remove all text in row after last / How could I do it using awk or sed? Or maybe some perl or python script? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

```
$ echo http://site1.com/lalala/ | sed -e 's;\(.*/\).*;\1;'
http://site1.com/lalala/
$ echo http://site1.com/lalala/foo.html | sed -e 's;\(.*/\).*;\1;'
http://site1.com/lalala/
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you'd use `dirname()` on the string. Is PHP one of the possible scripting language?

**EDIT:**

Perl and Python both have `dirname()`, am not so sure of the implementation. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the language used, I would split all lines (with \n as separator) to an array, then I would perform a search for the lastIndexOf "/" of each element, then I would remove the part I don't need using regular String methods. For sure you can do something interesting with RegExp too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/[^\/]*/\1/g'
```

Examples:

```
bash-$ echo "http://site1.com/lalala.html" |sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/[^\/]*/\1/g'
http://site1.com
bash-$ echo "http://site2.com/lalala/" |sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/[^\/]*/\1/g'
http://site2.com/lalala
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/"; } { $NF = ""; print; }'
```

Examples:

```
$ echo http://site1.com/lala/la.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/"; } { $NF = ""; print; }'
http://site1.com/lala/

$ echo http://site1.com/lala/ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/"; } { $NF = ""; print; }'
http://site1.com/lala/
```